# Custom Fonts are not showing properly?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios6, fonts

Perhaps it is the duplicate one, but I have still issues.

I have downloaded the custom fonts from the following link,

http://cooltext.com/Download-Font-Traditional+Arabic

Install it on my mac, saved in plist properly and then used as following.

```
lblDesc.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arabic" size:10];
```

After downloading I have changed it's name to Arabic, it's still not showing, can any one help me?

Thanks!
Regards!
Khalid Usman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use real font family name instead of file name.

> lblDesc.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Traditional Arabic-Regular" size:10];

Alternatively you can find out all the font install and check the name of the font of your interest

> ```
> for (NSString *familyName in [UIFont familyNames]) {
>     for (NSString *fontName in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName]) {
>         NSLog(@"%@", fontName);
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: @Parser, I am facing the same problem with this font , can you help me? http://www.fontpalace.com/font-download/MyriadPro-Regular/

Comment: use "Myriad Pro-Regular" in the font name and add filename "Fonts provided by application" in info plist

Answer (score 2):

The following steps should do the trick:

1. Import the .ttf or .otf file into your Xcode project
2. In your `info.plist` file, add the field "Fonts provided by application", which should be an array where you can add the font file name. Be sure to use the exact file name there (i.e. "Arabic-font.ttf"
3. In your implementation, use the full name of the font as you had before and NOT the file name.
   i.e.  `[UIFont fontWithName:@"Traditional Arabic-Regular" size:10];`

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the ttf / otf to the project?

Do you have the font installed on your mac using Font Book? 
If so, are you using  PostScript name from the Font book?

If not, try it.